# How can I make a select element transparent in Smelte.js?

Tags: css, forms, svelte

I am working on a project with Svelte and the material design library *[Smelte](https://github.com/matyunya/smelte)*:

```
<script>

const currency = [
    { value: 1, text: "EUR" },
    { value: 2, text: "GBP" },
    { value: 3, text: "USD" }];

</script>

<Smelte.Select label="Currency" class="bg-transparent inline-block">
    <div slot="options" class="elevation-1">
        {#each items as item}
            <div class="p-2">{item.text}</div>
        {/each}
    </div>
</Smelte.Select>
```

I have unsuccessfully tried to *make the select-box transparent* with CSS: `background-color: transparent` and `appearance: none` have both failed.

How can I achieve this?

## Edit

The select tag I use in the HTML generates an input of type 'readonly' which the CSS selector `input:read-only` does not target.

## Observation

In Angular Material there is the possibility to add `appearance="standard"` to a select element, to give it the classic underline look. It does not seem to work in Smelte.

Comment: Have you tried the classes "visible" and "invisible"? [reference here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/visibility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked here https://svelte.dev/examples#select-bindings and I am able to change bg color of that select box simply with.

```
select {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

maybe your css rule with transparent bg color is overridden by another css rule? You can try to add !important to your css rule or make selector heavier, like

```
form#id_of_parent_form select#my_select_id {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: It does not work with ` background-color: transparent !important` either. The select tag I use in the HTML generates an input of type 'readonly' which the CSS selector `input:read-only` does not target!

Comment: Using `!important` is like bringing a nuke to a knife fight. It kills all your cascading specifity. Only use it as a last resort.